Ubuntu 24.04 gnome-remote-desktop breaks audio on host system
I have A PC and a notebook. Both run on Ubuntu 24.04. Starting a remote desktop session from PC to notebook with gnome-remote-desktop works, but it destroys audio on the notbook the moment it is connected. I tried to purge pipewire, but ended up with no gnome-shell anymore. So gnome-remote-desktop is totally dependent on the pipewire package, even stops working when there is no pipewirte around. When the notebook tries to make a sound it just crackles and cracks very loud, sometimes gets stuck in a loop and does not stop until i terminate the remote session. Then sound works partially again. Funny thing: i dont need audio at all. It does not seem to be possible to disable it and removing also breaks things. Also after gnome-remote ruined audio, some other apps like teams can no longer properly detect audio hardware. So after using the notebook remotely i now have to restart it so i can go in a teams meeting. Very annoying.

I don't know if this will solve the problem with pipeware and sound. But it is worth a try.
Try xrdp
xrdp is the "traditional" RDP protocol server for Linux. You can disable "Gnome Remote Desktop" in Gnome Settings" and install xrdp with the command:
sudo apt install xrdp

This is a drop-in replacement for Gnome Remote Desktop. Your RDP client in the local computer should work without any changes in settings.
xrdp is more fully featured. Here are two other Q&A about  limitations of Gnome Remote Desktop, and xrdp as solution:
How to disable logoff on session disconnect in Ubuntu native RDP
how can I use Ubuntu 24.04 remote login for hyper-v enhanced session?
See the Original Answer for Ubuntu 22.04 section of Ubuntu 22.04 remote desktop headless? for more details.
Hope this helps

@user15972 i have an answer. See if it works for you. Leave a comment below if you try it.
